# Equal number and date being treated as different when comparing them

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform to edit a main database:
[image]

I use Vlookup to fetch details in the userform when a serial number is input.

```vb
Private Sub txtSerial_AfterUpdate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    Dim nwb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("Online sharepoint location")
    Set sh = nwb.Sheets("Summary")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("A:A"), EditForm.txtSerial.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This is an incorrect ID"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    X = EditForm.txtSerial.Value
    With EditForm
    
        .txtProject = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 3, 0)
        .txtTeam = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 4, 0)
        .txtAPL = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 5, 0)
        .txtAE = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 6, 0)
        .cmbRelease = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 7, 0)
        .cmbDS = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 8, 0)
        .txtBatches = CInt(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 9, 0))
        .dtReview.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 10, 0)
        .dtSubmission.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 11, 0)
        .dtRelease.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 12, 0)
        .dtPlanned.Value = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 13, 0), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        .cmbPriority = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 14, 0)
        .txtRemarks = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 15, 0)
        .txtQA = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(EditForm.txtSerial), sh.Range("A:R"), 17, 0)
        
    
    End With
    nwb.Close
End Sub
```

I am also trying to edit the database and track the changes.

```vb
Sub Edit()
'On Error GoTo eh
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    
TryAgain:
    Dim nwb As Workbook
 
    Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("Online sharepoint location")
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(nwb.Sheets("Audit Trail").Range("A:A")) + 1
    
    nwb.Sheets("Summary").Unprotect Password:="pass"
    nwb.Sheets("Audit Trail").Unprotect Password:="pass"
    Dim id As Range
    Set id = nwb.Sheets("Summary").Range("A:A").Find(what:=EditForm.txtSerial.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    oldValues = ""
    newValues = ""
    titles = ""
    
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 2), EditForm.txtProject.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 3), EditForm.txtTeam.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 4), EditForm.txtAPL.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 5), EditForm.txtAE.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 6), EditForm.cmbRelease.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 7), EditForm.cmbDS.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 8), EditForm.txtBatches.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 9), EditForm.dtReview.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 10), EditForm.dtSubmission.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 11), EditForm.dtRelease.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 12), EditForm.dtPlanned.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 13), EditForm.cmbPriority.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 14), EditForm.txtRemarks.Value
    LogChanges id.Offset(, 16), EditForm.txtQA.Value
    nwb.Sheets("Summary").Protect Password:="pass"
    
    
    If Len(titles) > 0 Then
            
        
            With Worksheets("Audit Trail")
            
                .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 1
                .Cells(iRow, 2) = EditForm.txtSerial.Value
                .Cells(iRow, 3) = titles
                .Cells(iRow, 4) = oldValues
                .Cells(iRow, 5) = newValues
                .Cells(iRow, 6) = frm6.txtJust.Value
                .Cells(iRow, 7) = Application.UserName
                .Cells(iRow, 8) = [Text(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")]
                
            End With
            
            nwb.Sheets("Audit Trail").Protect Password:="pass"
            'nwb.Sheets("Audit Trail").Visible xlSheetVeryHidden
            
        End If
        Unload frm6
        'MsgBox (titles)
        'MsgBox ("Changes edited succesfully and recorded in Audit trail sheet")
    
    'nwb.Save
    nwb.SaveAs Filename:="Online Sharepoint location"
    nwb.Close
    MsgBox ("Changes edited succesfully and recorded in Audit trail sheet")
    Unload EditForm
Exit Sub
'eh:
    'Ans = MsgBox("Another user is submitting their entry, please wait for a few seconds and then try again.", vbRetryCancel + vbCritical)
    'If Ans = vbRetry Then Resume TryAgain

End Sub
```

LogChanges function:

```vb
Sub LogChanges(c As Range, vNew)
    With c
        sep = IIf(Len(titles) > 0, "; ", "") 'need a separator?
        If .Value <> vNew Then
            'track the changes
            titles = titles & sep & .Parent.Cells(1, .Column).Value 'column titles in Row1
            oldValues = oldValues & sep & ValueOrBlank(.Value)  'track old value
            newValues = newValues & sep & ValueOrBlank(vNew)    'track new value
            .Value = vNew                                       'update the cell
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function ValueOrBlank(v)
    ValueOrBlank = IIf(Len(v) > 0, v, "[blank]")
End Function
```

Everything is working as expected except two fields:
Number of Batches - A number
Planned release date- A textfield date. I have to keep that date in textfield because it is not a mandatory field.

Here is a screenshot of the audit trail sheet:
[image]

In the last row you can see the number of batches and Planned date. They shouldn't have come as I didn't change them.

Regarding number of batches I tried putting text there and then it started working properly. So the problem is because it is a number.

Comment: I assume EditForm.txtBatches.Value holds a string value while a number on a sheet is converted to numeric type

Comment: I checked the sheet, it is numeric type. This is the reason, I added the CInt to try to convert the txtBatches value to numeric. But it didn't had any effect

Comment: A textbox will contain string value even after `CInt`. The ultimate comparison is done in `LogChanges` so I'd rather apply `CInt` there like `LogChanges id.Offset(, 8), CInt(EditForm.txtBatches.Value)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my issue. Do you have a solution for the date problem as well? It has to do with format I think

Comment: Different date formats make a regular issue and I don't see an elegant solution. I'd parse them and compare the year, month and day values separately.

Answer (score 0):

Number of batches - try forcing each item you compare into a number type first, then compare the two forced number variables to each other.

Date problem - you have elected to use text due to date not mandatory. I suggest using date types, and solving the effect on "not mandatory" in another way. For example:

- Validation as date or empty/blank
- Interpret 0 (which displays as 1/1/1900 or 1/1/1904 etc in excel) as zero, null or blank instead of parsing the date, leaving only actual dates stored as dates

Storing as data types will avoid the date issues you are seeing with regional display options showing different text representations of date input, and many other similar issues as well.